# правильные ссылки и хлебные крошки

Tags: wordpress

Скажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать. Вот я, например, создала кастомный тип "Преподаватели", адрес соответственно будет `http:/your_site/prepodavateli` а мне необходимо, чтобы было `http:/your_site/school/prepodavateli` . И соответственно, чтобы `wps_yoast_breadcrumb();`  содержали `"Домик-Школа-Преподаватели"` вместо `"Домик-Преподаватели"`. Это можно сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста, со структурой, как лучше сделать. Вот есть пункт меню- "Школа", содержащие подпункты:

1. расписание занятии, кружков (у меня это страница)
2. история школы (у меня это страница)
3. Преподаватели (кастомный тип записей, просто записи мне не подходит)
4. Желающим поступить (у меня это страница) 
            4.1 Устав школы (страница) 
            4.2 Памятка ученику (страница)
5. Контактная информация (у меня это страница)

У меня была создана рубрика в записях "школа", потом я к этой рубрике прикрепляла страницы, вследствие чего у меня отображалось нормально: Домик-Рубрика-Страница.
Но меня не устраивает создавать в записях подрубрику "преподаватели" рубрики "школа".   И я не хочу содержать в записях рубрику" школа",  хочу ее убрать.  Можно было сделать Страницу "Школа", а к ней подстраницы... Но нельзя записи, кастомный тип записей привязывать к странице. И это печалька...Что можно сделать? Или я неправильно разметила информацию?
PS: Нужно, чтобы при клике на школу в хлебных крошках, было выведено описание страницы, если это, например, можно выведено для собственных таксономии. Есть ли смысл создавать новый тип записи, в котором будут создаваться таксономии для страниц, постов, и кастомных типов записей? Наверное, туплю...

```html
function true_apply_categories_for_pages2(){
 add_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'Категории', 'post_categories_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'normal'); // добавляем метабокс категорий для кастомного типа преподаватели
 register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'page','prepodavateli'); // регистрируем рубрики для страниц, не работает
 //register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post','prepodavateli'); // регистрируем рубрики для страниц, работает
}

// обязательно вешаем на admin_init
add_action('admin_init','true_apply_categories_for_pages2');
```

Comment: хлебные крошки !=соответственно урлу. Если это понять и принять, то многое станет на места.

Comment: я понимаю, и знаю. Но вопрос в том, как это это сделать. Я не хочу рубрики создавать в посту. Кажись, об этом я писала... Спасибо.

Comment: "Я не хочу рубрики создавать в посту." А в ХК тогда что?

Comment: д
     
Все понятно, кажется я это описала.... "у меня была создана..." Но мне необходимо другое. Сформулирую вопрос: как вы бы с моим меню сделали структуру сайта в wd? Если учесть , что некоторые пункты меню-страницы, и кастомный тип "преподаватели". Вам удобно было хранить в записях и преподавателей, и новости, цитаты, вопрос-ответ? Дело в удобстве, как мне кажется..

Comment: `register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'prepod'); // регистрируем рубрики для типа преподаватели`  не меняет ссылки.

Comment: или я что-то не понимаю...